# how can I put disable validation on running app asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, validation, webforms

How can I put disable the cause validation property of a control while the app is running cause that I have a radio button that put disable a control but this still cause validation

I put this but not worked.

```
text.CausesValidation = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an asp validator, you will want to disable the *validator* to skip validation for the control it is validating.

For example..if you have

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFV_Text" runat="server" ... >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

then in the server code, disable by

```
RFV_Text.enabled = false;
```